# Echo PHP Array as a String

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to echo the array below that I have pulled from my AD and have it echo out like this:

FWADMIN, SA, K2ADMIN, CONFERENCEROOM

```
Array
(
[FWADMIN] => Array
    (
        [email] => fadmin@fwslash.com
        [first_name] => FW
        [last_name] => Admin
    )

[SA] => Array
    (
        [email] => sadmin@fwslash.com
        [first_name] => SQL
        [last_name] => ADMIN
    )

[K2ADMIN] => Array
    (
        [email] => kadmin@fwslash.com
        [first_name] => K2
        [last_name] => ADMIN
    )

[CONFERENCEROOM] => Array
    (
        [email] => croom@fwslash.com
        [first_name] => Conference
        [last_name] => Room
    )

)
```

I have tried things like

```
$separator = implode(", ", $ad_users);
echo $separator;
```

and I get 20 error messages of 'array to string conversion'

Comment: `echo join(', ', array_keys($ad_users));`

Comment: you have an array-of-arrays, you can't implode the parent array, because the child arrays won't implode themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and I get 20 error messages of 'array to string conversion'

That's because `implode()` tries to cast each *element* of the array (another array) into a string; the result is a warning for each cast attempt and the final result of `"Array, Array, Array, ..."`.

Use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array_keys) first to get the *keys* of your array instead:

```
echo join(', ', array_keys($ad_users));
```

It creates a new array with only the keys of the given array, in the same order; the keys are either an integer or string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
echo implode(", ", array_keys($ad_users));
```

Comment: Could you add a little explanation of what your code is doing?

Comment: @SiKing: First it is creating a new array from the keys of $ad_users. Then it is joining the elements of this new array with ", " between each element.